# Listen to a different IP address

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code:

```
var server = express();

// Create the HTTP server
http
    .createServer(server)
    .listen(80, '10.10.10.10');
```

Once the server has been started, how can I dynamically change the listened IP address, say to `11.11.11.11` instead of `10.10.10.10`. Is there an "unlisten" method?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @robertklep: I want to restart the server with a different IP address without killing the process.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you have to use server.close() not app.close()..

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  ...
})

server.listen(8000,'127.0.0.1',function(){
 server.close(function(){
   server.listen(8001,'192.168.0.202')
 })
})
```

should work

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, and `server.close` will not unbind the `127.0.0.1` address.

Comment: maybe there are some open connections? see http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback

Comment: Nope. I even get an uncaught exception `[Error: Not running]`.

Comment: did you place the close function in the callback as i did in the code above? listen is also async so you can't close the server if it isn't listening yet..

Comment: Yep, I copy pasted your code, and removed the `app.get` line. Try it!

Comment: i tried this on node v0.8.19 and express@3.1.0 this does work for me

Comment: Works here too, even with the same port number on both `listen`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "unlisten" function  you're looking for is called "close": http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback

Comment: That doesn't work with Express. `Uncaught exception!
 [TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'close']`

Answer (score 1):

```
app.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0',function(){
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.1.1:8000/')
})
```

will work with express

Answer (score 0):

What your are trying to accomplish is quite non-standard in my opinion. I would suggest [server.close()](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback). Close will wait all request to finish and trigger the "close" event. You can bind on that event to listen on the new IP. This is quite weird tho.

Comment: That doesn't work with Express. `Uncaught exception!
 [TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'close']`