# How to run Vue cli with Webpack on live server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Yesterday I bought a droplet from digital ocean, to start learning new stuff direct on a live server.
I started with `Vue`. I followed the `Vue cli` with `webpack` installation guide. All went well.

The problem I have is when I access the url. For example: `127.12.22.33/test/testvue` app I get a white page, without any `Vue`.

When I run `npm run dev`, it tells me to access `localhost:8080`, but of course won't work. If I access `127.12.22.33:8080` I get

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error

The Question:

How to make it work on a live server(not local), when I access the url to display the `vue` code? I guess something I am missing or something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're running vue dev server on localhost, and as a result, it is not accessible publicly. In order to make it publicly available open the `build/dev-server.js` and change the these lines:

```
module.exports = app.listen(port,'0.0.0.0' ,function (err) {
if(err){
console.log(err)
return
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. I already used http://my-ip:8080 but still got connection timed out error. what you told me to change was a console output but not how to make it work.....

Comment: Changing the console.log won't affect the dev-server. Check-out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003947/listen-to-a-different-ip-address). Change `app.listen(port, callback)` to something like `app.listen(80, '0.0.0.0', callback)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer but the problem was elsewhere.

`http://my-ip:8080/` was not working becouse port `:8080` was not allowed by the firewall. Soon after I found that the droplet image comes with a firewall.

Had to run next command to add port to firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```