# Node.JS with Express, script complies but does not create an http server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a MEAN stack, and I changed the hosted IP address for MongoDB and Angular so that the site can be accessed remotely. Now, my Node.JS/Express backend is not working. The script compiles, it shows the 'Server started' but there is no http server running on port 3000. I do not know enough to put in error-checking code..

```js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var app = express();
var route = require('./route/routes.js');

require('./model/players');
require('passport');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.1.3:27017/elo', {useNewUrlParser: true});

mongoose.connection.on('error',(err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

const PORT = 3000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/api', route);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({"messege" : err.name + ": " + err.message});
    }
});

app.get('/',(req, res) =>{
    res.send("App Works");
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

Comment: You said you changed the IP for Angular, what do you mean by that? Are you trying to access this server through an IP address?

Comment: I see where you changed the connection for mongoose, but Im not seeing where you change it for your node server. Have you checked to see it is still running as localhost?   Take a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003947/listen-to-a-different-ip-address

Comment: I used ng serve --host=IP.ADDRESS to run the Angular client. I used the same kind of thing for MongoD. I don't know how to do the same for nodemon, my research just shows "it doesn't matter it all gets seen"

Comment: I am able to run a different block of code with nodemon and have it successfully listen on port 3000, so it's not an environment issue....

Answer (score 0):

Found the offending code:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, but as soon as I comment it out, 'App works'