# Node.js Application Trying to Listen on Wrong IP

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

I have a Node.js application that I am trying to run on a pod in a local K8s cluster. I am getting am EACCES permission denied error when I try to start the app with `app.listen(8989, '0.0.0.0')`

```
[2023-10-10T18:58:01.462Z] [INFO]    process exiting
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied tcp://10.101.19.227:8989
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1355:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1519:5)
    at Function.listen (/ipm-service/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at /ipm-service/index.js:108:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/ipm-service/index.js:12:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'tcp://10.101.19.227:8989',
  port: -1
}
```

The IP above (10.101.19.227) is the IP of the K8s Service, not the Pod that it is running on. If I delete the K8s Service and start the application again, it works fine.
I'm at a loss as to how the application is getting the IP of the Service instead of the Pod IP.

I've tried changing the listen command to
`app.listen(8989, 'localhost')`, `app.listen(8989)`, and even `app.listen(8989, 127.0.0.1)` and it always tries to listen on the Service IP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous answer from [supernova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003947/listen-to-a-different-ip-address) that can help with your concern. It should be server.close() not app.close()

For example:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  ...
})

server.listen(8000,'127.0.0.1',function(){
 server.close(function(){
   server.listen(8001,'192.168.0.202')
 })
})
```